# Maven testng group test run NPE

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Created test automation framework maven+testng+selenium + appium.
Running  testng 'maven test' or  'mvn test -Dgroups=SignUp'
Error shown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project TestPageObject: Exception in provider: NullPointerExcepti
on -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project TestPageObject: Exception in provider
```

POM.xml:
      `<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>reporter.debug</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!--<testdroidDevice>${value}</testdroidDevice>-->
                        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                        <groups>
                            SignUp,
                        </groups>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>`

testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Custom suite" verbose="1">
  <test name="MeWe-PO" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.appium.test.AppTest"/>
    </classes>

    <groups>
  <define name="all">
    <include name="SignUp"/>
    <include name="Login"/>
  </define>
  <run>
    <include name="all"/>
  </run>
</groups>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Used annotations @BeforeGroups or @BeforeSuite

Debug and stacktrace :

```
    [DEBUG] Output directory: E:\MeWe\Projects\MeWePO\target\test-classes
[DEBUG] CompilerReuseStrategy: reuseCreated
[DEBUG] useIncrementalCompilation enabled
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ TestPageObject ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=114, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.t
opsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=34, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=80, DefaultDepen
dencyCollector.collectTime=213, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=3}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.19.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.19.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.19.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]             junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[DEBUG]                org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]             backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:202)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.InPluginVMSurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(InPluginVMSurefireStarter.java:82)
        ... 25 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Add debug traces and stacktrace of maven: --debug and -X in command line.

Comment: <groups>SignUp **,** </groups> is it ok?

Comment: Any way throw it away because suiteXmlFiles overrides all other configs